# Python: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, sum

code for finding the large sum in the array:

```
def maxsum(arry):
    if len(arry)==0:
        return 0
    summ,maximum_sum=0
    for i in arry:
        summ=summ+i
        maximum_sum=max(summ,maximum_sum)
    return maximum_sum    
maxsum([1,2,-1,-2])
```

getting the following error: `TypeError`

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-59dc92538282> in <module>
      7         maximum_sum=max(summ,maximum_sum)
      8     return maximum_sum
----> 9 maxsum([1,2,-1,-2])
     10 

<ipython-input-5-59dc92538282> in maxsum(arry)
      2     if len(arry)==0:
      3         return 0
----> 4     summ,maximum_sum=0
      5     for i in arry:
      6         summ=summ+i

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Comment: You can not set two variables like `summ,maximum_sum=0`. But you can use something like `summ, maximum_sum = 0, 0`.

Comment: ...or `summ = maximum_sum = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error due to variable assignment.

```
def maxsum(arry):
if len(arry)==0:
    return 0
summ,maximum_sum=0,0 # Changes
for i in arry:
    summ=summ+i
    maximum_sum=max(summ,maximum_sum)
return maximum_sum
```

https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-multi-variables-values/

cannot unpack non-iterable int object :

---------This is because it tried to convert it to tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Change summ,maximum_sum=0 by:

```
summ=0 
maximum_sum=0
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Klaus D also

```
def maxsum(arry):
    if len(arry)==0:
        return 0
    summ,maximum_sum=0, 0
    for i in arry:
        summ=summ+i
        maximum_sum=max(summ,maximum_sum)
    return maximum_sum    
maxsum([1,2,-1,-2])
```